# How to make Linux domain service accessible globally

Tags: linux, network-shares, domain, network-discovery

I am working on a case study where there is a company which has a couple of windows system like Windows home and pro running windows based software.

The company wants to expand globally and for that, they are setting up a new office in Singapore and they want to set up IT infrastructure there.

There is 1 System Administrator and he wants to create a domain. So basically the company wants to connect all the systems in the network domain to communicate and share resources, see each other etc..

But when the Administrator could not can not through a domain because the reason is different operating systems ranging from window 7 to windows 8 and also **Windows 7 home doesn't support domains**.

So they came up with the idea of using Linux Zorin which emulates the windows environment and also Linux is free because the company doesn't want to spend money.

But I don't know how to make Linux domain service accessible globally?

Comment: I think you first need to describe what "domain service" you _have_, because such things aren't nearly as integral part of Linux as they are on Windows...

Comment: @user1686 So basically company wants to connect to all the computers across the globe through a single domain

Comment: @user1686 They want to set up a domain where computer can talk to each other but problem is all the systems are using different operating systems like windows 7 home as mentioned in the question

Comment: But computers can already talk to each other, that's called "the internet". What _actual functions_ do you it expect to provide? File sharing? Central password database? Group Policy?

Comment: @user1686 A secure mechanism to share files, communicate with each other etc without cost

Comment: there is ALWAYS a cost, if not for OSes, then for the admin who needs to set it up and be paid for or - if he is already getting paid - then it will cost him a lot of time to research and set it up. So the Business Owner and the IT must be in sync what they want to achieve in what time and how it will be managed afterwards. This all just saying there is no short answer for your question. Some companies might have greater costs to switch to free Linux OS as it might be that they don't have any employee who is able to maintain such an environment.

Comment: And regarding Windows Home - those are (as the name states) meant to be used in non-corporate environments. With that said - you can use them in an corporate network - but you can't maintain them centrally. They can access domain integrated file shares with the annoyance to need to authenticate on access. And Zorin is considered a Desktop OS. You did not mention any Server OS, nor central file system storage, so as user1686 asked, what is your intention for file sharing?